# Disable notice yii

Tags: yii, notice

How disable notice , i try in idex.php But Notice is echo , how i can disable this .

```
<?
    define("YII_ENBLE_ERROR_HANDLER",false)
    define("YII_ENBLE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER",false)
?>
```

in php.ini

```
<?display_errors = off ?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update public/index.php

```
<?php
define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
define('YII_ENABLE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER', false);

// Turn off all error reporting
// error_reporting(0);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Add define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false) to index.php and then set error reporting.

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$edited in E:\web\domains\cabinet\protected\views\timeshares\index.php on line 34

Comment: You should disable YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER in public/index.php, not in app/views/timeshares/index.php

Comment: this is my index.php  <?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',false);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER',false);
define('YII_ENABLE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER',false);
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

Comment: There is a type in your answer, cant edit because one character: `YII_ENBLE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER` should be `YII_ENABLE_EXCEPTION_HANDLER` - **same typo is in question**